# gdb catchpoint on write syscall not working

Tags: gdb, clang, llvm

I am debugging an issue I found in the clang compiler on GNU/Linux (reported [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30413)).  To find the problem, I need to debug backward from the point where clang writes the output file.

I tried setting a catchpoint on the write syscall:

```
(gdb) catch syscall write
Catchpoint 2 (syscall 'write' [1])
```

I also set a breakpoint:

```
(gdb) break write
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7ffff6a7c700: write. (2 locations)
```

But when I compile a test program, no breakpoint is triggered: gdb just exits normally.  I confirmed that it writes the output file, so write must be getting called somewhere.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one "most common" possibility, debugging `clang` rather than `clang -cc1`. The driver re-execs itself in order to make providing stack traces and other things easier via catching errors in spawned programs and if you're debugging `clang` it won't be able to set a breakpoint since it won't have called any code that you have a breakpoint in.

You can use clang with -v to get a -cc1 command line and then set gdb --args to that.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I did not know about clang -cc1.  To debug -cc1, would I just add -cc1 to my command line arguments?

Comment: Thanks so much!  I ran my initial command with -v, then set my gdb args to that, and the breakpoint was triggered!  Much appreciated!  I've marked this as the answer.